# Is there a real solution to $3^x=3-x$?

Tags: logarithms

I ran into this one in IB math HL, had no clue how to to solve it.  Is there a way to solve without graphing?

Comment: The question in the title does not seem to match the question in the post. Do you need to prove the existence of a solution, or find the solution itself?

Comment: You may be new here, so I'd like to let you know that you can comment and [edit] your posts to improve their quality, else they will likely be downvoted and closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exact answer require the [Lambert $W$-function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

You need:

$$(3-x)e^{-x\log 3}=1$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{3\log 3}\log(3)=3^3\log 3:$

$$\left((3-x)\log 3\right)e^{(3-x)\log 3}=3^3\log 3$$

Or:

$$(3-x)\log 3 = W\left(3^3\log 3\right)$$

And thus:

$$x=3-\frac{1}{\log 3}W\left(3^3\log 3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course.

Let $f(x)=3^x+x$.

Hence, $f$ increases and $f$ is a continuous function.

Also, $f(0)<3$ and $f(1)>3$.

Thus, our equation has an unique real root.

Comment: You don't mean real root. You mean that there's a unique $x$ with $f(x)=3$. (I don't usually refer to a solution of an equation as a root. But you mean the original equation.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Which I showed.Number $a$ is named the root of the equation $f(x)=0$ if $f(a)=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That was the OP's question.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I don't mean to make a mountain out of a mole hill, but then shouldn't you have $f(x) = 3^x+x-3$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin In my definition of the  equation root you can change $f$ on $g$ if you wish. In my solution of the starting problem I used $f(x)=3^x+x$. See please better my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowing the use of a calculator or computer using Newton's method, you might as well go directly to computer-based symbolic math. 
 *Mathematica* gives the answer directly:

$x = \frac{3 \log (3)-W(27 \log (3))}{\log (3)}$

where $W$ is the Lambert W function or PolyLog function.  Its numerical value is $0.741552$, which comports with a graph of $3^x + x - 3$:

[image]

Comment: Bah, I got that exact formula with no computer aid. :)

Answer (score -1):

My original answer: To solve the equation, use Newton's method. Look it up in your calculus book.

Edit: In this answer, I am going to make some comments about pedagogy, about the culture of math.stackexchange,  and about the mathematics. All the comments are serious.

Math.stackexchange has many roles.  It is a world-wide office hour and a world-wide math department coffee lounge.  It is evident from the question posed here that what is called for is an office hour response. In fact, we have a student who is learning secondary level mathematics in a course, or on his own, and is bringing not a homework question, but something that puzzled him from his text.  He is showing intellectual curiosity.   The response that he got was to tell him to go away (4 downvotes, question closed, go away, don't come back).   Why?  It wasn’t clear whether he was asking about the existence of the solution or about finding the solution.  Why not just assume he was asking about both and address both questions, while giving some gentle advice about how to pose a question more precisely, since that is also something that he also needs to (gradually) learn?  Maybe the student has learned a valuable lesson:  mathematicians are unfriendly, study something else.

Finally, let’s come to the mathematics.  One answer to the original question, by [Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg), addressed the existence question in a pedagogically appropriate way.  Two other answers by [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews) and [David Stork](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/210401/david-g-stork) address the question of finding the solution, and propose to find the solution “exactly” in terms of the Lambert W function.   The Lambert W function is the inverse function to  $x \mapsto x e^x$, while the original question requires an inverse to $x \mapsto 3^x + x$.    Let’s call the latter function  (i.e. the inverse to $x \mapsto 3^x + x$)  the Stackexchange G function.    Now I can tell you the “exact" solution to our problem:  it is $G(3)$.    This is true, exact and completely uninformative.
The solution by TA and DS consists of doing some manipulations involving algebra and exponential and log functions to show that
$$ G(a) = a - \frac{1}{\log(3)}  W(3^a \log(3)),$$
so a (only slightly) different “exact” solution to our problem is
$$G(3) = 3 -  \frac{1}{\log(3)}  W(27 \log(3)).$$
This is true, exact, and nearly as uninformative as the answer $G(3)$.  Maybe it is even more uninformative than the answer $G(3)$ because it has the aura of authority, so we don’t necessarily notice that we don’t know what we are talking about.

It’s very nice that we have names for important transcendental functions,  sin, cos, log, exp, maybe some others.   If the answer to a real world problem comes out as  $\sin(1/2)$  I think we can be very happy with that and consider it as an exact solution, even though we would have to use some computer algorithm to get an actual numerical approximate value. That’s because the sin function is our intimate friend.  Not so the Lambert W function, at least not for me.  For me, the Lambert W function is really no better than the Stackexchange G function.

How would we evaluate either the Lambert W function or the Stackexchange G function?  Newton’s method, I think.  Thus my original suggestion to go learn Newton’s method.  The Lambert W function is something pretty special, but Newton's method is a Big Idea. For secondary student who has been lead to believe up to now, that solving equations always should mean finding an exact formula, it is liberating to learn that one can solve a great variety of equations using a fairly simple idea from calculus, if one gives up the idea of an exact solution.